# How to find specific numbers of repeating consecutive digits?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble making this function evaluate if a a six digit integer has either a set of two repeated consecutive digits or four. All other sets of repeated consecutive digits should evaluate to false.

Examples of good input: 122345, 133335

Bad input: 123335, 666478

Here is my code:

```
bool hasDuplicate(int number){

    int rem, num, dig;
    
    do {
        rem = number % 10;
        num = number / 10;
        dig = num % 10;
        if (rem == dig) {
             return true;
        }
        else {
            return hasDuplicate(num);
        }

    } while (number > 0);

    return false;   
 }
```

Comment: what did you see when stepping through with vs debugger?

Comment: The issue is that after rem is found to be equal to dig it will not compare the other digits in the integer. My test case is "235559" and it should be false. The debugger says no errors or warnings.

Comment: well thats what the code says to do :-), me I would not do it recursively, nor would I do the math. I would convert to a string to start and simply walk down the string looking at the chars

Comment: A debuggers job is not to tell you about errors, its job is to help you walk through the code. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: If you want to keep this structure dont just say 'return true' if 2 match , have a match counter. add 1 to it when you get a match. Say true if match = 2 or 4. You need to reset if non match, plus since its recursive (ugh) you need to pass match down the recursion

Comment: It is uncommon to see a loop like this inside a recursive function. Usually the recursion IS the loop.

Comment: I took off the loop. Its was irrelevant. I am in my second programming class so I'm a bit of a newb. I will try the counters.

Comment: What if the number was `223334` ?

Comment: Selbie that would be false because there is still a set of three threes. Thank you!

Comment: Up until the question starts receiving answers feel free to update the question to match what you're currently working on. After the question starts getting answers you need to be careful to not invalidate any correct answers. This means if you asked the wrong question and someone successfully answered the question you did ask, you're kind of stuck. But until then, open game. Just don't answer the question in the question.  If you solve the problem yourself, write an answer.

Comment: Really learn to use your debugger. If it Visual Studio (I assume it is ) its really simple. Select a line in the code with your mouse and press F9, now run the program. See?

Comment: Extending on above [here's a good tutorial on using a debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022). It's Microsoft-specific, but at this point pretty much all of the debuggers work the same way. Other IDEs will just move the buttons around.

Comment: When manipulating or playing with digits of numbers, consider treating the number as a string.  You can convert the digit character to a digit number with: `int digit_number = number_as_text[index] - '0';`

Comment: bad inputs should return false? It's not clear example !

Answer (score 1):

Consider converting the number to string and then just scanning the characters in the string from left to right.

```
bool hasDuplicate(int number) {

    std::string s = std::to_string(number);

    bool good = false;
    bool bad = false;
    int consecutive = 1;

    // deliberately starting at s[1]
    for (size_t i = 1; i < s.size(); i++) {
        bool dupe = (s[i - 1] == s[i]);

        if (dupe) {
            consecutive++;
        }

        // last iteration or this char is not a duplicate of the previous one
        if ((i + 1 == s.size()) || (!dupe)) {
            bool good_sequence = (consecutive == 2) || (consecutive == 4);

            good = good || good_sequence;

            bool bad_sequence = (consecutive == 3) || (consecutive > 4);
            bad = bad || bad_sequence;
            
        }

        if (!dupe) {
            consecutive = 1;
        }
    }

    return good && !bad;
}
```